# Guzzle 6 bulk Httppost requests to shopify api

Tags: php, heroku, http-post, guzzle6, shopify-app

I'm creating orders with shopify web app using php, Guzzle 6 hosted on Heroku. Following code snippet is used.

```
        //json encode
    $orderdata = array(
        'order' => array(
        'line_items' => array(
                    0 => array(
                        'title' => 'Avocado',
                        'quantity' => 1,
                        'variant_id' => 42837938757,
                        'vendor'=>'Saaraketha Organics',
                        'product_id'=>9043955845
                        ),
                    )
            )
        );
    $order = json_encode ($orderdata);
        $logcontent = "$order\n";
    file_put_contents("php://stderr", $logcontent);

    //create client and post data
        $url =(string)('https://api_key:password@domain/admin/orders.json');
        $client = new Client();
        $RequestResponse = $client->post($url, ['headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'], 'body' => $order]);
```

Although it successfully creates orders, it repeatedly occurs.

This is the Heroku log I got.
[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2L7t.png)

[image]

Comment: What do you mean it repeatedly occurs? I see no reason the script would make the request more than once

Comment: When I check on Shopify Shopfront, once 191 orders created, second time 181 orders created till I commit again the code with errors, intentionally to prevent it. I have no idea why it happens.

Comment: I think the problem is with $client->post() syntax. Tried with wrong $url to check it, I could see 6 requests has been sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.
The app is being called on Order Creation webhook. Within the same app controller it post orders, which again triggers same webhook, making an infinite sequence of requests.